# Extract Specific Cell Values out of a Raster Brick

Tags: r, extract, raster

I have calculated the Wind Speed and Wind Direction from two Raster Bricks.

Now I want to extract the Maximum Wind Speed for each cell. I did that. Now the problem is that I also need the Wind Direction for that specific cell.

my code looks like this:

```
speed <- brick(speed)
direction <- brick(dir)
maxWindspeed <- max(speed, na.rm = TRUE) # this gives me a raster with the Max Wind Speed Values
```

Anyone has an idea how to get the specific Wind direction cell for the Max Wind Speed cell in the "maxWindspeed" layer?

Best Regards
Max

Comment: Can you not pick wind direction by using `maxWindspeed[maxWindspeed$...,]` ? can you give an example of your raster by calling it on r and pasting its layout here?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I have understood correctly what you want to do but maybe you can try this:

```
library(raster)
#simulate data
r <- s <- t <- raster()
r[] <- sample(1:10,ncell(s),replace = T)
s[] <- sample(2:11,ncell(s),replace = T)
t[] <- sample(3:13,ncell(s),replace = T)

speed <- brick(r,s,t)
direction <- brick(r*s,s/t,t-r)
#max values across layers in speed
maxWindspeed <- max(speed, na.rm = TRUE)
plot(maxWindspeed)
plot(direction)
#boolean raster of where maxWindspeed is max
masker <- maxWindspeed==max(maxWindspeed[])
#brick of values in direction where maxWindspeed is max
plot(maxdirection <- mask(direction,masker,maskvalue=0))
#max values across layers in maxdirection
maxdirectioncell <- max(maxdirection,na.rm = T)
plot(maxdirectioncell)
```

Answer (score 0):

With `raster` you can use `which.max` and `stackSelect`. Using Elia's (slightly modified) example data

```
library(raster)
r <- s <- t <- raster(ncol=10, nrow=10, crs="+proj=utm +zone=1 +datum=WGS84")
r[] <- sample(1:10,ncell(s),replace = T)
s[] <- sample(2:11,ncell(s),replace = T)
t[] <- sample(3:13,ncell(s),replace = T)
speed <- stack(r,s,t)
direction <- stack(r*s,s/t,t-r)

mxspeed <- which.max(speed)
sdir <- stackSelect(direction, mxspeed)
```

With `terra` you can use `selectRange`

```
library(terra)
spd <- rast(speed)
dir <- rast(direction)

mxspd <- which.max(spd)
sd <- selectRange(dir, mxspd)
```